# `Ansible-playbook` command fails when run from a non-root user

Tags: linux, ansible, openshift, rhel8

I am trying to run an ansible-playbook from the `cloud-user(non-root)` user on the RHEL machine. The playbook requires sudo access, for which I have used the below command -

```
 ansible-playbook -i inventory -e @install_vars.yaml playbooks/install.yaml --become-method=sudo --become
```

On using the `become` it has solved the issues encountered earlier of the package installations.
However, I get the following error:

```
fatal: [ash-test-bb22-bastion-0]: FAILED! => {"changed": true, "cmd": "openshift-install create manifests --log-level info", "delta": "0:00:00.002662", "end": "2022-01-20 04:36:30.224594", "msg": "non-zero return code", "rc": 127, "start": "2022-01-20 04:36:30.221932", "stderr": "/bin/sh: openshift-install: command not found", "stderr_lines": ["/bin/sh: openshift-install: command not found"], "stdout": "", "stdout_lines": []}
```

`openshift-install` executable is available under the `/usr/local/bin` directory and works fine when the user is root.

PATH also has it defined.
`PATH=/home/cloud-user/.local/bin:/home/cloud-user/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/sbin`

Am I doing anything wrong? Can anybody tell me the exact command for the ansible-playbook for the above scenario?

Comment: The error comes from your target, not from your local shell where you execute ansible, i.e. the command does not exist / is not in the path when logued on ash-test-bb22-bastion-0

Comment: So, what could be done in such a case? Any suggestions? @Zeitounator

Comment: Either Install the missing command on the target or make it available on the path either by including it in the default/non-login sh path (used by ansible and which most probably does not include `/usr/local/bin`) by moving/copying/making a symbolic link or by changing the path in an [`environment` stanza](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_environment.html) to include the needed folder. Repeating a bit of the above, remember that ansible uses sh by default and does not launch a login shell so does not read any of your shell init files (`login`, `.bashrc`, etc...)

Comment: the missing command `openshift-install` is already installed on the target and it is also available on the PATH on the target machine. Tried running the command from the non-root login and it works.

Comment: There is no way to infer from your above test that the given command is in the path for the root user using a non-login sh shell from ansible. Just echo the `$PATH` var from a become command task in an ansible playbook and you will see for yourself. Hint: if it was there and in the path, you would never have asked the above question and we would never have had this conversation. Good luck.

Comment: @Zeitounator Thanks a lot for your help :) I'll give this a try.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested by @Zeitounator, I modified the /etc/sudoers file and updated the $PATH variable which solved the above issue.